# Multiple templated functions interact

Tags: c++, function, templates, template-function

I have been having trouble getting my `findNth` templated function to use my helper function `quicksort`. I keep getting "Use of undeclared identifier 'quicksort'" as if there is no matching function call. Any idea what is going on?

```
#ifndef ORDER
#define ORDER

#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename T,typename C>
T &findNth(std::vector<T> &data,int index,const C &comp){

    quicksort(&data, 0, data.size()-1);

    return data[index];
}
```

And here is my quick sort function.

```
template<typename T,typename C>
void quicksort(std::vector<T> &data, int lo, int hi){
    if(lo < hi){
        int p = partition(data, lo, hi);
        quicksort(data, lo, p - 1);
        quicksort(data, p + 1, hi);
    }
}
```

All of the other quicksort helper functions are written up, but haven't been causing any issues to my knowledge.

Comment: The compiler needs to see quicksort before it's called. Place it above the findNth function. Be aware there is a built-in sort function.

Comment: if you are encountering "Use of undeclared identifier 'quicksort', maybe it's the problem of `include`?

Comment: [The code compiles without error](http://ideone.com/n5ZVYr)

Comment: I tried to switch the order and am still getting errors on my end that it cant find the function - thanks for the advice everyone

Comment: @NeilKirk Since `quicksort()` is dependent wouldn't its definition only be needed when `findNth()` is instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you fixed the order, you still have a problem has `C` is non deductible and not provided (and unused BTW).
So transform your `quicksort` to something like:

```
template<typename T>
void quicksort(std::vector<T> &data, int lo, int hi);
```

or:

```
template<typename T, typename C>
void quicksort(std::vector<T> &data, int lo, int hi, const C&c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your quicksort function before findNth? :

```
#ifndef ORDER
#define ORDER

template<typename T, typename C>
void quicksort(std::vector<T> &data, int lo, int hi) {
    // your code here
}

template<typename T,typename C>
T &findNth(std::vector<T> &data,int index,const C &comp) {
    // your code here
}
```

Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know quicksort when you call it.